# What's taking Sin City 2 so long?

Tags: production, sin-city-a-dame-to-kill-for

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sin_City_%28film%29#Sequel), Robert Rodriguez announced that he would do *Sin City 2*.  The latest update, according to Wikipedia, is that they're almost done writing the script.  Is there any indication as to why it's taking so long for *Sin City 2* to come to fruition?

I'm not looking for speculation or discussion, I'm looking for concrete sources.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[One of the issues that took so long was the funding, which Rodriguez only in August announced was in place](http://www.joblo.com/horror-movies/news/robert-rodriguez-offers-up-another-sin-city-2-update-funding-script).

No one is going to write a sequel on spec, so that was a big component. William Monahan was brought in at the end of the summer to [rewrite Miller's screenplay](http://screenrant.com/sin-city-2-writer-william-monahan-sandy-129549/). Rodriguez still claims that once the script is in place they can start shooting. It is clearly still "not in place."

Keep in mind, too, Frank Miller was in "movie jail" after the disaster that was The Spirit. This is an unspoken predicament that happens often in Hollywood where someone puts out a film that is a financial and critical disaster. They wind up having to wait a few years before getting a chance to jump back in to actual production.